# Restrict android app install on devices

Tags: android

In iOS, we have provisional profiles to setup device UDIDs. So, our app will install on devices only which UDIDs are added to provisional profile at development stage. We generally added only customer device. So only customer can install the app. The build will not install any other device.

Is there any feature like above in Android?

NOTE: I knew we have feature in Google Play. But, I need this feature while development.

Comment: [Start your search here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/console.html).

Comment: I suggest you reread your apple developer agreement about the way you are using your provisioning profiles to circumvent sales in the app store.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter which **users** (not devices) can install your app.

In order to do that, use Google Play Developer Console to publish *beta* application APK - it can be installed only once user joins specific Google+ community or Google group.

So you have to create such a group or community and make it private - this will allow you to filter out which users can join.

After those users join, you will send them test URL and app will be installed on their devices.

Have a look [at this Google Play Help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The Play Store's method of doing this is via the new [beta-testing feature](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). You add your testers to a Google+ community, and they get access to your application via the Play Store.

If you don't want to use the Play Store, you can implement a restriction within the app itself to accomplish this. The [Identifying App Installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) Android Blog post has some great information on how to uniquely identify devices. You can use one of these methods to check the device's identifier against a list of "approved" devices in your Activity's `onStart()`, and simply call `finish()` if the user is not "approved."